# C : Conversion between Infix to postfix (Unary Operations:Minus)

Tags: c, postfix-notation, unary-operator

I already have an algorithm on how to convert infix to postfix expressions but it is only limited positive numbers. My problem is:

1. How about if there are negative numbers in the infix expression.
2. Is there another algorithm for converting infix to postfix with negative numbers?
3. How then do I evaluate the postfix expression?
4. How can i edit my code to suit u-nary minus?

for example:
infix:
-4*(4+9*5+-(9+-4/2))=
postfix: ?

My code used ->

```
void infixTopostfix(char infix[], char postfix[],int x)
{
    int i,j=0;
    stack s;
    intialize(&s);
    for(i=0,j=0; i<x ; i++)
    {
        if(infix[i]>='0')
        {
            postfix[j]='(';
            j++;
            for(; (!value(infix[i]))&&(infix[i]!=')')&&(infix[i]!='\0'); i++)
            {
                postfix[j]=infix[i];
                j++;
            }
            postfix[j]=')';
            j++;
            i--;
        }
        else if(infix[i]=='(')
        {
            push(&s,infix[i]);
        }
        else if(infix[i]==')')
        {
            while(top(&s)!='(')
            {
                postfix[j]=pop(&s);
                j++;
            }
            pop(&s);
        }
        else if(infix[i]<'0')
        {
            while((value(infix[i])<=value(top(&s)))&&(!isempty(&s)))
            {
                postfix[j]=pop(&s);
                j++;
            }
            push(&s,infix[i]);
        }
    }
    while(!isempty(&s))
    {
        postfix[j]=pop(&s);
        j++;
    }
    postfix[j]=0;
}

float evaluate_postfix(char postfix[])
{
    int i,j;
    float p,r;
    char number[10];
    stack s;
    intialize(&s);
    for(i=0; postfix[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        switch (postfix[i])
        {
        case '+':
            r=pop(&s);
            p=pop(&s);
            push(&s,r+p);
            break;
        case '/':
            r=pop(&s);
            p=pop(&s);
            push(&s,p/r);
            break;
        case '*':
            r=pop(&s);
            p=pop(&s);
            push(&s,r*p);
            break;
        case '-':
            r=pop(&s);
            p=pop(&s);
            push(&s,p-r);
            break;
        default:
            i++;
            for(j=0; (postfix[i]!=')')&&(postfix[i]!='\0'); i++)
            {
                number[j]=postfix[i];
                j++;
            }
            number[j]='\0';
            push(&s,atof(number));
        }
    }
    return pop(&s);
}
```

Comment: The key words would be "Polish notation" and "Reverse Polish Notation (RPN)". Now you can google it.

Comment: I Already know how to convert BUT only with postive values , but for no, i can't handle Negative values .. is there "Specific" Link or something, please? @EugeneSh.

Comment: You would handle negatives by checking if the previous token before the negative sign is not a number, then negating the next number. Or you would define a new operator in your post fix expression called # or something that represents Unary Minus.

Comment: What after defining a new operator? how to evalute it :D That's my problem and thats why i threw my code :D